# R shiny imageOutput size change

Tags: r, shiny

I have images of size 1770x2101 pixels (l.png,n.png,a.png) and need to render 100 * 300 pixel size

ui

```
imageOutput("myImage", width = "100%", height = "300px"))
```

server

```
output$myImage <-renderImage({
if (input$l == 'l') Leg<-"www/l.png"
if (input$l == 'n') Leg<-"www/n.png"
if (input$l == 'b') Leg<-"www/b.png"
if (input$l == 'a') Leg<-"www/a.png"
list(src=Leg)
},deleteFile = FALSE)
```

But image is not resizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the dimensions in `renderImage`:

```
list(src = Leg, width = "100%", height = "300")
```